# Google Cloud SQL: driver: bad connection although different projects work

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-sql

I am currently trying to deploy another app on GAE using a Google Cloud SQL instance. I already have 2 services running on there with the same setup also using a Cloudsql instance. However, when I am trying to connect to Cloudsql from my newest service, I am getting a "driver: bad connection" error and I can not figure out why. I am using the `_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"` driver as follows:

```
var (
DB_INSTANCE            *sql.DB
)
...
configFile := GetConfig()
user := configFile.DatabaseReaderHost.DatabaseUser
password := configFile.DatabaseReaderHost.DatabasePassword
dbName := configFile.DatabaseReaderHost.DatabaseName
connectionName := "project-id:region:instance-name"

if appengine.IsDevAppServer() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?parseTime=true",
        user,
        password,
        configFile.DatabaseReaderHost.DatabaseHost,
        configFile.DatabaseReaderHost.DatabasePort,
        dbName))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    DB_INSTANCE = db
    return nil
} else {
    dbn, err := sql.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@cloudsql(%s)/%s", user, password, connectionName, dbName))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    DB_INSTANCE = dbn
    return nil
}
```

What I noticed is that the connection to the Cloudsql instance seems to be established since the above code is not what produces the error, but my test query agains the database.

```
func TestDatabaseHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
var name string
err := DB_INSTANCE.QueryRow("SELECT name FROM names WHERE id = ?", 1).Scan(&name)
if err != nil {
    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        PrintSingleResponseJson(w, "error", fmt.Sprintf("no rows found"))
    } else {
        Log(r, fmt.Sprintf("Could not connect to database: %v", err))
        PrintSingleResponseJson(w, "error", fmt.Sprintf("could not connect to database: %s", err))
    }
    return
}
PrintSingleResponseJson(w, "success", fmt.Sprintf("%s", name))
}
```

I appreciate all help.